# How to select random method using perform selector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, random, performselector

In my application I use `performSelector` to call methods. I have three different methods in my application, I want that randomly I assign one of these three methods to perform selector. Here is my code.

```
[self performSelector:@selector()];
```

Here is my three methods..

```
-(void)Act1
{
}

-(void)Act2
{
}

-(void)Act3
{
}
```

Now I want to assign each time one method randomly to selector. Can any one guide me how I can do this.

Comment: 1 to 3 random number generator... then if-else if condition...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int rand = (arc4random() % 3) + 1;
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Act%d",rand])];
```

Comment: when i implement your code it give me error.. error: expected ')' before '(' token

Comment: @Albert.: sorry for that, i was writing directly. I corrected the code. It will give you leak warning - you can suppress this warning #pragmas that Stanislav mentiones.

Answer (score 4):

Use an array of selectors, `SEL` is their type.

```
SEL mySelectors[3] = { @selector(Act1), @selector(Act2), @selector(Act3) };
[self performSelector:mySelectors[rand() % 3]];
```

You may want to suppress the warning issued by ARC about a potential memory leak, it's safe since your methods are `void`. Use `objc_msgSend` or wrap the code like this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [self performSelector:mySelectors[rand() % 3]];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: i implement your method but every time it call Act2.

Comment: That's correct, because you must initialize the random number generator with `srand()` before using `rand()`, which will give you the same sequence each time the app restarts if you don't initialize it.

Answer (score 3):

You could put 3 strings in an array representing your methods, pick randomly one and the use Nsselectorfromstring to get your selector